# String Index Out Of Range: -1 error

Tags: java, hadoop, emr

String Index Out Of Range: -1 is the error I get when I execute this code in my mapper in hadoop MR.

```
    String line = value.toString();
    String[] longLatArray = line.split(",");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble((longLatArray[0]).substring(1));
```

line looks like this: "(-21.24132363125682,-175.14134768396616,1)"

My aim is to remove the first "(" and get just -21.2873623 into my lat variable.

edit:

When I tried to debug in the hadoop interface, this is what I got:

```
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: line: (-21.24132363125682,-175.14134768396616,1)
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 0
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: (-21.24132363125682
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 1
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: -175.14134768396616
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 2
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: 1)
```

When I executed very similar code just locally, I did not get any errors

Also, what is the significance of the -1 here?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: if line is "" then you'll get -1. it means you are not getting the value you are expecting in 'value'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    String value="(-21.2873623,160.2323,1)";
    String line = value.toString();
    String[] longLatArray = line.split(",");
    double lat = Double.parseDouble((longLatArray[0]).substring(1));
    System.out.println(lat);
}
```

That is working as intended for me, giving me the lat from the coords in `value`. This leads me to believe that there is an issue with whatever is in `value`. Are you sure that value contains what you are expecting it to? You can debug by doing a:

```
System.out.println(value); // or use a logging library
```

And verify that. The -1 leads me to believe that you have passed the end of the string, but I'm not 100% positive on that.

Comment: Yes, I printed it out in the hadoop interface!, and this is what I got:            attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: (-21.24132363125682,-175.14134768396616,1)
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 0
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: (-21.24132363125682
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 1
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: -175.14134768396616
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: index 2
attempt_201406251613_0002_m_000000_0: 1)

Comment: @aishpr You should put that into your question, so it is clear to other readers and so it can be properly formatted.

Comment: I don't suppose that it is looping through many different coords, and one happens to fail? Or you have a typo you are overlooking? From what I can tell your code should work.

Comment: Okay, maybe there is a "\n" that is in excess in the previous value. So I'm putting a check for the length of longLatArray to be 3 and executing that (the entire file is formatted that way), and will let you know what comes out of that

Comment: It seems to be working now! You were right about value not giving me what I expected! Thanks :)

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help!

Answer (score 0):

```
 indexOf() returns -1 when the argument can't be found. It Might be the root Cause.    

 Reproducible code   
String value="";         
String line = value.toString();     
String[] longLatArray = line.split(",");        
double lat = Double.parseDouble((longLatArray[0]).substring(1)); 
System.out.println(lat);
```